# Сборка .exe из под Linux

Tags: linux

Доброго времени суток товарищи кодеры, а кодерам линуксоидам вдвойне!
Меня интересует седующий вопрос:
**Каким способом наиболее эффективно собрать код в exe-шник?**
Имеется в виду не просто сборка с заданным разширением, но и работоспособность в осях Win. Как консольные, так и проги с собственным интерфейсом.
**Как это делаете вы?** Если делаете.
Использовать виртуальную машину или поставить Win не имею возможности.
**Что если через установить например VS или Delphi, запускать это wine'ом, писать на них с использованием библиотек WinAPI и как результат собирать, то будет ли полученный файл юзабелен под Windows?**
Если вы посоветуете кроссплатформенный компилятор, то накидайте небольшое HowTo или линк на него пожалуйста.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Что если через установить например VS или Delphi, запускать это wine'ом, писать на них с использованием библиотек WinAPI и как результат собирать, то будет ли полученный файл юзабелен под Windows?

Да, это возможно. Получаемый исполняемый файл будет такой же как при сборке под Windows. Единственный нюанс связан с тем, что VS и Delphi являются серьезными программными комплексами и их произвольная версия с произвольной версией wine и linux может быть просто неработоспособна. Но с достаточно старыми и 'зрелыми' версиями студий проблем не будет.

> Каким способом наиболее эффективно собрать код в exe-шник?

Компилятором, поддерживающим кросс-компиляцию. Это означает, что компилятор будет под linux, а выходной код - под windows. Ищите в гугле по ключевым словам gcc, cross-compile, windows. Еще рекомендую обратить внимание на проекты Mingw32 и Cygwin: они позволяют писать программы под windows с помощью gcc, т.е. можно делать переносимые программы между средами linux и windows с одним исходным кодом, путем простой перекомпиляции.

Comment: И снова спасибо вам

Answer (score 2):

Правильно gecube говорит:

> Еще рекомендую обратить внимание на проекты Mingw32 и Cygwin: они позволяют писать программы под windows с помощью gcc, т.е. можно делать переносимые программы между средами linux и windows с одним исходным кодом, путем простой перекомпиляции.

Вот как для С у меня в Geany выглядят пораметры сборки:
Скомпилировать UNIX: gcc -lm -o "%e" "%f"
Скомпилировать WIN:  i586-mingw32msvc-gcc -o "%e".exe "%f"
Сборка: gcc -Wall -c "%f"

Выполнить: "./%e"
Выполнить EXE: "./%e".exe

Answer (score 0):

А может, попробовать что-то вроде Java или интерпретируемых языков - Perl, Python, Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

Собранный под Wine exe будет. А так читать про Lazarus (и FP); умеют кросс-компиляцию Mono, 
а так же про GCC и его ключи.

Answer (score 0):

В продакшине используют виртуальные машины, если проц поддерживает встроенную виртуализацию, то ставьте paralels, если нет, то virtualbox. На среднем компе клиентская виртуалка с Windows или linux-ом работают достаточно шустро; я так с C# работаю.